# Optimización de procedimiento almacenado

Tags: sql, sql-server

Dispongo de un procedimiento almacenado que recoge campos de diferentes tablas y suma la cantidad de *OK* y *NOK*.

Realiza bien la consulta, pero el tiempo de ejecución supera muchas veces el minuto, TablaUno consta de cientos de miles de registros y por ello no puedo poner un ejemplo funcional, he identificado algunas cosas que pueden generar la ralentización pero no consigo agilizarlo, dejo a continuación las tablas y la consulta:

###### TablaUno

```
IdTablaUno PK int not null         
IdUsuario int not null             
Fecha datetime not null        
NumSerie nvarchar(20) not null      
Resultado nvarchar(20) not null
Imagen image null
FechaBaja datetime null
FechaActualizacion datetime null  
IdUsuarioActualizacion int null
Comentario nvarchar(200) null
IdTablaDos FK int null
```

###### TablaDos

```
IdTablaDos PK int not null
IdTipoTabla int not null
Direccion nvarchar(50) not null
Descripcion nvarchar(200) null
Campo nvarchar(20) not null
IdTablaTres FK int not null
```

###### TablaTres

```
IdTablaTres PK int not null
Numero nvarchar(255) null
Descripcion nvarchar(255) null
IdOtraTabla int null
```

###### TablaCuatro

```
IdTablaCuatro PK int not null
Nombre nvarchar(255) null
Descripcion nvarchar(255) null
Codigo nvarchar(20) null
```

##### Procedimiento Almacenado

```
USE [BBDD]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[IN_DATOS_CONTROLPRODUCCION]
(
       @FECHAINI datetime,
       @FECHAFIN datetime,
       @CELULA int
)
AS
BEGIN
       -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
       -- interfering with SELECT statements.
       SET NOCOUNT ON;

       SELECT distinct A.IdTablaTres, A.Numero, A.Celula, A.IdTablaDos, A.Puesto, A.IdTablaCuatro, A.Nombre, format(A.Fecha, 'dd/MM/yyyy') as Fecha,
       'T' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, A.Turno) as Turno, 
       (SELECT COUNT(RESULTADO) FROM TablaUno rp
             INNER JOIN TablaDos pt on pt.IdTablaDos = rp.IdTablaDos
             INNER JOIN TablaTres ce on ce.IdTablaTres = pt.IdTablaTres
             INNER JOIN TablaCuatro ref on substring(rp.NumSerie,0,8) = ref.Codigo 
             WHERE Resultado = 'OK' 
             AND pt.IdTablaTres = A.IdTablaTres AND ce.Celula = A.Numero AND ce.Descripcion = A.Celula AND rp.IdTablaDos = A.IdTablaDos
             AND pt.Descripcion = A.Puesto AND ref.IdTablaCuatro = A.IdTablaCuatro AND ref.Nombre = A.Nombre 
             AND rp.fecha >= @FECHAINI and rp.fecha <= @FECHAFIN
             and CONVERT(DATE, rp.fecha) = CONVERT(DATE, A.Fecha) 
             and dbo.IN_GETTURNOBYFECHA(rp.fecha) = A.Turno
       ) as OKs,
       (SELECT COUNT(RESULTADO) FROM TablaUno rp
             INNER JOIN TablaDos pt on pt.IdTablaDos = rp.IdTablaDos
             INNER JOIN TablaTres ce on ce.IdTablaTres = pt.IdTablaTres
             INNER JOIN TablaCuatro ref on substring(rp.NumSerie,0,8) = ref.Codigo 
             WHERE Resultado = 'NOK' 
             AND pt.IdTablaTres = A.IdTablaTres AND ce.Celula = A.Numero AND ce.Descripcion = A.Celula AND rp.IdTablaDos = A.IdTablaDos
             AND pt.Descripcion = A.Puesto AND ref.IdTablaCuatro = A.IdTablaCuatro AND ref.Nombre = A.Nombre 
             AND rp.fecha >= @FECHAINI and rp.fecha <= @FECHAFIN
             and CONVERT(DATE, rp.fecha) = CONVERT(DATE, A.Fecha) 
             and dbo.IN_GETTURNOBYFECHA(rp.fecha) = A.Turno
       ) as NOKs
       FROM
       (
             SELECT pt.IdTablaTres, ce.Numero as Numero, ce.Descripcion as Celula, rp.IdTablaDos, pt.Descripcion as Puesto, 
             ref.IdTablaCuatro, ref.Nombre, rp.NumSerie, 
             dbo.IN_GETFECHATURNO(rp.fecha) as Fecha, dbo.IN_GETTURNOBYFECHA(rp.fecha) as Turno, 
             Resultado
             from TablaUno rp
             INNER JOIN TablaDos pt on pt.IdTablaDos = rp.IdTablaDos
             INNER JOIN TablaTres ce on ce.IdTablaTres = pt.IdTablaTres
             INNER JOIN TablaCuatro ref on substring(rp.NumSerie,0,8) = ref.Codigo
             where rp.fecha >= @FECHAINI and rp.fecha <= @FECHAFIN and pt.IdTablaTres = @CELULA
       ) A

END
```

Ya teniendo todos los datos me dispongo a enumerar los puntos que he visto que pueden causar ralentización:

1. `INNER JOIN` Si lo cambiamos por `LEFT JOIN` es más ágil.
2. `substring`
3. `dbo.IN_GETTURNOBYFECHA(rp.fecha)` Llamar a otro procedimiento
4. Subquerys en vez de `UNION`

¿Qué otros motivos puede haber que generen ralentización?

Comment: Esto no tiene que ver con el query en sí pero tienen índices o se pueden crear en las tablas que tienen más datos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varios motivos. El principal que se puede solucionar de inmediato, es que estás leyendo las tablas 3 veces. Simplemente necesitas usar agregado condicional en vez de usar subconsultas.

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT  pt.IdTablaTres,
            ce.Numero as Numero,
            ce.Descripcion as Celula,
            rp.IdTablaDos,
            pt.Descripcion as Puesto,
            ref.IdTablaCuatro,
            ref.Nombre,
            CONVERT( VARCHAR(10), dbo.IN_GETFECHATURNO(rp.fecha), 103) as Fecha,
            'T' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), dbo.IN_GETTURNOBYFECHA(rp.fecha)) as Turno,
            Resultado
    FROM TablaUno           rp
    INNER JOIN TablaDos     pt  on pt.IdTablaDos = rp.IdTablaDos
    INNER JOIN TablaTres    ce  on ce.IdTablaTres = pt.IdTablaTres
    INNER JOIN TablaCuatro  ref on substring(rp.NumSerie,0,8) = ref.Codigo
    WHERE rp.fecha BETWEEN @FECHAINI AND @FECHAFIN
    AND   pt.IdTablaTres = @CELULA
)
SELECT IdTablaTres,
        Numero,
        Celula,
        IdTablaDos,
        Puesto,
        IdTablaCuatro,
        Nombre,
        Fecha,
        Turno,
        COUNT( CASE WHEN Resultado = 'OK' THEN 1 END) AS OKs,
        COUNT( CASE WHEN Resultado = 'NOK' THEN 1 END) AS NOKs
FROM CTE
GROUP BY IdTablaTres,
        Numero,
        Celula,
        IdTablaDos,
        Puesto,
        IdTablaCuatro,
        Nombre,
        Fecha,
        Turno;
```

El otro punto importante, es que estás usando funciones escalares de usuario. Esas funciones harán más lento el código porque evitan el uso de paralelismo. Hay formas de convertirlas a algo más eficiente, pero depende del código de cada una.

El último punto, es que estás usando `FORMAT()`, la cual es una función mal optimizada que es hasta 40 veces más lenta que `CONVERT()`. Eso también lo modifiqué en el código.

**Respecto a los motivos que mencionaste:**

Cambiar el tipo de JOINs no mejora el rendimiento. Es falso que uno se más ágil que el otro. Lo que cambia es la lógica y eso puede derivar en malos resultados.

Lo mismo al cambiar las subconsultas por `UNION`.

Respecto al `SUBSTRING()`, sí podría ser optimizado, pero solo si la columna codigo de TablaCuatro siempre tiene la misma longitud. De otra forma, también puede haber errores al unir las tablas por códigos incorrectos. En todo caso, se podría generar una columna en TablaUno que tenga el código separado del resto del número de serie.

Como mencionan en un comentario de la pregunta, también será importante ver los índices que se tienen para ver si falta alguno que pueda ayudar a hacer la consulta de forma más eficiente.